# Rename variables via lookup table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataframe in a certain order:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    foo = 1:3,
    bar = LETTERS[1:3],
    baz = rnorm(3)
  )

df

  foo bar         baz
1   1   A  0.41474174
2   2   B -0.08416768
3   3   C -0.27931232
```

In another dataframe, I have the old variable names matched to some new names, but in a ***different order***:

```
variable_match <- 
  data.frame(
    old = names(df)[c(2, 3, 1)], 
    new = LETTERS[1:3]
  )

variable_match
  old new
1 bar   A
2 baz   B
3 foo   C
```

My question is: How do I rename the variables in the original dataframe by looking up the corresponding value in the second dataframe. I'm ideally looking for a `tidyverse` solution. I have tried variations of:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% rename_at(variable_match$old, funs(variable_match$new))
```

assuming that rename_at would be the right approach, but this doesn't work. I'm wondering if `purrr::map_*` would be the right approach, but can't see how. Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What about using `plyr::mapvalues`

Comment: Maybe this works, but I cannot test it `df %>% rename_at(variable_match$old, function(x) variable_match$new[variable_match$old == x])`. I think @Gregor's answer is good though

Comment: You can port Gregor's answer easily with dplyr 0.6: `df %>% rename_all(funs(variable_match$new[match(., variable_match$old)]))`. You could also do `df %>% rename(!!!setNames(rlang::syms(as.character(variable_match$old)), variable_match$new))`, though I'm pretty sure there's a more elegant version of that with `:=` that I can't figure out how to write.

Comment: @alistaire thanks, that's basically what I was looking for. Looks like I need to get my head around the `rlang` package next

Comment: also `rename_(df, .dots = setNames(as.character(variable_match$old), variable_match$new))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a one-line `base` solution:

```
names(df2) = variable_match$new[match(names(df), variable_match$old)]
```

It may not be "ideal" for you (it doesn't need the `tidyverse` to work), but it is simple and doesn't require loading any extra packages, instead relying on common built-in functions.

---

As noted in comments, if you prefer a nested statement with pipes (aren't pipes intended to improve readability and prevent nesting?) the simple line above is equivalent to

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df = df %>%
    set_names(
        var_match %>%
        pull(new) %>%
        extract(
            names(df) %>% 
            match(var_match$old)
        )
    )
```

I'm a big fan of pipes and `dplyr` - I use them consistently when the make things simpler and more readable. In this case they take a simple line and turn it into a programming puzzle, both in how to write it and how to read it.

A nicer interface overall is the `data.table::setnames` function. If you convert to a datatable, then the code is `setnames(df, old = var_match$old, new = var_match$new)`. This is robust in case not all names are changed (see comments below).

Comment: thanks - this can be ported directly to the `tidyverse` by alistaire's comment above, or `df %>% 
  set_names(
    var_match %>% 
      pull(new) %>% 
      magrittr::extract(names(df) %>% match(var_match$old))
  )`

Comment: This works but what about if there is a few columns that don't match.  For instance your lookup table just references 80% of the fields in the original dataframe.  If the name isn't found in my lookup table then, then I wouldn't want to rename it, but the keep the name as.  This mapping gives it NA names for the fields that aren't in the lookup table

Comment: @runningbirds Yeah, OP's question was all about reordering, not about partial replacement. You could make small modifications so that only names that match are replaced: (calling the lookup table `vm`:  `names(df2)[names(df2) %in% vm$old] = vm$new[match(names(df2)[names(df2) %in% vm$old], vm$old)]`

Answer (score 3):

I functionalised Gregor's answer so it can be used easily within a pipeline:

```
lookup_rename <- function(df, column_lookup) {
  df2 <- df
  # using Gregor's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43742442/3927208)
  names(df2) = column_lookup$new[match(names(df), column_lookup$old)]
  df2
}
```

I hope this illustrates how `base` solutions can easily be used within the `tidyverse` philosophy. It might be worth adding in some error handling to the function too.