Need to use text values in one data set as variable labels for another data set in R
I have two data sets. Data set A has two columns as below.
[Data set A]



obs
col1
col2




1
dem_it1
Age


2
dem_it2
Gender


3
dem_it3
Race



Data set B has those values of column1 in Data set A as columns as below.
[Data set B]



obs
dem_it1
dem_it2
dem_it3




1
xxx
xxx
xxx


2
xxx
xxx
xxx


3
xxx
xxx
xxx



The goal is to label the columns in Data set B with the values of column2 in Data set A. I cannot figure out how to achieve this goal in R. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This sounds similar to these prior questions. Does these resolve it for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742369/rename-variables-via-lookup-table-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287155/rename-columns-using-values-from-separate-dataframe or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493635/how-to-rename-columns-in-a-table-by-using-a-table-of-old-and-new-names-in-r-tid

names(b)[-1] <- a$col2?

If you are a user of the tidyverse packages, particularly dplyr you could do the following...
library(dplyr)

#Create a named vector of old names, and new names.
name_vector <- A %>% pull(col1)
names(name_vector) <- A %>% pull(col2)


rename(B, all_of(name_vector))

The tidy selection all_of() forces strictness when renaming. But depending on your exact use case and rigidity you could modify this.
Cheers

Thanks! The first two lines work, but the rename function gives me an error for "all_of()": "! Can't subset elements. ✖ Subscript must be numeric or character, not a list." Any idea what's going on? @@
